# Error en interacción de ventanas con Python - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ventana

Hola comunidad hice este programa en python donde estoy teniendo dificultades. Este programa abre una ventana principal y después de apretar el botón "HD" la ventana principal debe de destruirse y abrir la ventana dos. Pero al hacerlo el programa se cierra y se queda en un loop en la consola como si lo siguiera ejecutando. ¿Alguien sabe por que pasa esto?

```
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import ttk

 ##############################################################
 ####################Funcion Main##############################

 def main():
    root=Tk()
    app=Window1(root)


 ###################Menu principal#############################

 class Window1: 
    def __init__(self, master):
       self.master=master
       self.master.title("Ebers.")
       self.master.geometry("1300x750+0+0")
       self.master.config(bg="black")
       self.frame=Frame(self.master, bg="gray")
       self.frame.pack()
    
       #Boton para cambiar de ventana
       self.btnHD=Button(self.frame, text="HD", width=17, command=lambda:[self.new_Window()])
       self.btnHD.pack()
   
       #Definimos la funcion que llamara a la otra ventana

       def new_Window(self):
           self.newWindow=Toplevel(self.master)
           self.app=Window2(self.newWindow)
           self.master.destroy()


 #######################Herramientas de diagnostico######################
        
  class Window2:
        def __init__(self, master):
           self.raiz=master
           self.raiz.title("Herramientas de diagnostico")
           self.raiz.geometry("1300x750+0+0")
           self.raiz.config(bg="gray")
           self.frame=Frame(self.raiz, bg="blue")
           self.frame.pack()
           self.raiz.mainloop()
    
          

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

En `Window1.new_Window` lo primero que debes hacer es destruir la ventana principal, y la nueva ventana tiene que ser un objeto `Tk`, no un `Frame` que dependa de la ventana principal:

```py
def new_Window(self):
    self.master.destroy()
    self.newWindow=Tk()
    self.app=Window2(self.newWindow)
```

Una vez hecho esto, en `Window1.__init__` no olvides ejecutar `self.master.mainloop()`.

Un saludo!